# How to delete one side of a triangle in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

Is there any way to draw triangle (I mean `GL_TRIANGLES`) without one side? In example, making diagonal line here to disappear:

[image]

Comment: Instead of 2 triangles, draw 4 lines

Comment: Well, that's not the question I asked

Comment: Well, what is the difference between a triangle without one side, and two lines? If I ask "how do I draw pentagons with 3 sides" the answer is "draw triangles"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [edge flags (`glEdgeFlag()` & co.)](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEdgeFlag.xml) to do so:

[image]

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main( int, char** )
{
    glfwSetErrorCallback(
        []( int, const char* desc )
        {
            std::cerr << desc << "\n";
            std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        } );
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow( 320, 240, "GLFW", NULL, NULL );
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );
    gladLoadGLLoader( (GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress );

    float verts[] = {
        -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1,
    };

    GLboolean flags[] = {
        GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_FALSE,
    };

    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        int w, h;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize( window, &w, &h );
        glViewport( 0, 0, w, h );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho( -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1 );
        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
        glLoadIdentity();

        glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT, GL_LINE );

        glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
        glEnableClientState( GL_EDGE_FLAG_ARRAY );
        glEdgeFlagPointer( 0, flags );
        glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
        glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, verts );
        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6 );
        glDisableClientState( GL_EDGE_FLAG_ARRAY );
        glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );

        glfwSwapBuffers( window );
    }

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how could I use these flags when I have a massive of vertices (something like `float vertices[] = {// first triangle -0.9f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -0.45f, 0.5f, 0.0f,  // second triangle 0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  0.9f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  0.45f, 0.5f, 0.0f  };`)?

Comment: @Noerig: [`glEdgeFlagPointer()`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEdgeFlagPointer.xml)

Comment: Don't really understand how to implement it...

Comment: Note that `glEdgeFlag` only works for the old fixed pipeline OpenGL.